# symfony 5 samesite=none firefox

Tags: symfony, console, csrf, samesite

i have a console error only on Firefox when using Synfony 5, i check everywhere for finding a solution but i see on a symfony issue that the problem come from to Firefox and I would like to be sure or find a solution about that.

Console error:

The "sf_redirect" cookie will soon be rejected because its "SameSite" attribute is set to "None" or an invalid value and it does not have the "secure" attribute. To learn more about the "SameSite" attribute, see https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite
The "sf_redirect" cookie was rejected because it has already expired.

Symfony 5 framework.yaml

```
framework:
secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
#csrf_protection: true
#http_method_override: true

# Enables session support. Note that the session will ONLY be started if you read or write from it.
# Remove or comment this section to explicitly disable session support.
session:
    handler_id: null
    cookie_secure: auto
    cookie_samesite: lax

#esi: true
#fragments: true
php_errors:
    log: true
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: cookie samesite]
Like you can see I have got the attribute secure in my cookie, and this problem appears only after update the entities in my database by my CRUDS.
In my last comment i refer to [issues](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/37301) after some search I find this [Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1651618) apparently even Firefox 80 have some difficulty and probably fix the issue soon.
Thank you for your message and wish you the best.

Answer (score 0):

Cookie `SameSite=None` works only with `Secure`. For more information you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite#Fixing_common_warnings). Also, how to set cookies in [symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#setting-cookies)